# How to move `ApplicationUser` to a domain project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I wish to move the template generated `ApplicationUser` to another, data layer, project. I have read umpteen answers here that simply say "just move it", but I don't know how their authors missed the elephant in the room that is `GenerateUserIdentityAsync`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

This depends on `ApplicationUserManager`, which I can't get into my domain project without a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer: 
 So i recommend to parse the information from the result and pass your custom object to your project

Thanks.

Comment: Async has nothing to do with this. The above class, in my domain project,  requires a reference to my web project for the `ApplicationUserManager`, but my web project already needs a reference to the domain project.

Comment: if you domain project is either business or data layer don't ref ApplicationUserManager over there. Parse the result and pass it to your domain project.

Comment: Yeah I know that... you are trying use the ASP.NET class inside your class library. So i recommend to parse the information from the result and pass your custom object to your project.

Comment: Yes, I created a `IdGenerator` class in the web project, so it doesn't have to call a method on `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: have you created IdGenerator class now to parse the information or you have this class already to making a call from your domain project to web project?

Comment: Yes, the IdGenerator is in the web project, and I just pass in manager and user and it passes back the Id. Just replaced a `this` in the original with a new `user` parameter. Stupid of then to make that not optionally dependent on the entity, especially since it's pure Identity code that does it. Change your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: That's great... updated the answer from my comments.. :) Thanks @ProfK